# How to iterate through a html of texts and attributes in their correct order using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

How do you iterate through a html of texts and attributes  in their correct order using JSoup.

```
<a href="link1"> text child 1</a>
own text 1
<b> text child 2</b>
own text 2
```

I want to do some processing for each attribute / text. 
e.g. final output may be something like the following: -

```
1) text child 1 (is a link)
2) own text 1 
3) text child 2 (is bold)
4) own text 2
```

currently, I can iterate the children elements

```
Elements elements = element.children(); //gives my child 1 and 2;
for(element e: elements){ 
    //... do processing plus extract childText... 
}
```

or get OwnText,  but I don't know how to do both together.

```
String text = element.ownText(); // gives me own text 1 and 2;
```

Also, I do not want to use (because the row information is lost)

```
String text =element.Text();
```

How can I iterate through element such that i can get

```
child 1 -> text 1 -> child 2 -> text 2 (where text 1 and 2 are separated)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your HTML is not very complex you could use:

```
for (Node node : document.body().childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode) node).text());
    } else if (node instanceof Element) {
        System.out.println(((Element) node).ownText());
    }
}
```

If it is more complex, you could go recursively through the element tree:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup
                .parse("<a href=\"link1\"> text child 1</a>\r\n" + "own text 1\r\n" + "<b> text child 2</b>\r\n" + "own text 2");

        handleElement(document.body());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void handleElement(Node parent) {
    if (parent instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode) parent).text());
    }
    for (Node node : parent.childNodes()) {
        handleElement(node);
    }
}
```

This code prints out what you described:

```
int counter = 1;
for (Node node : document.body().childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(counter++ + ") " + ((TextNode) node).text().trim());
    } else if (node instanceof Element) {
        Element element = (Element) node;
        String suffix = "";
        if ("a".equals(element.tagName())) {
            suffix = " (is a link)";
        } else if ("b".equals(element.tagName())) {
            suffix = " (is bold)";
        }
        System.out.println(counter++ + ") " + element.ownText() + suffix);
    }
}
```

> 1) text child 1 (is a link)
>   2) own text 1
>   3) text child 2 (is bold)
>   4) own text 2