# Getting data in order with Jsoup

Tags: java, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to get data from html in order from a web. Html code looks like:

```html
<div class="text">

First Text
<br>
<br>
<div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
 <table cellpadding="5">
 <tbody><tr>
  <td class="alt2">
    <div>
     Written by <b>excedent</b>
    </div>
    <div style="font-style:italic">quote message</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody></table>
</div>Second Text<br>
<br>
<img class="img" src="https://developer.android.com/_static/images/android/touchicon-180.png"><br>
<br>
Third Text
</div>
```

What I want to do is create an Android layout scraping html, but I need to preserve the order of the elements. In this case:

> 1. TextView => First Text
> 2. TextView => Quote Message
> 3. TextView => Second Text
> 4. ImageView => img
> 5. TextView => Third Text

The problem comes when I try to get html values in order, using JSoup I get a String with "First Text Second Text Third Text" with Element.ownText, an then img at the end, resulting:

> 1. TextView => First Text Second Text Third Text
> 2. TextView => Quote Message
> 3. ImageView => img

What can I do to get that data in order?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754677/how-to-iterate-through-a-html-of-texts-and-attributes-in-their-correct-order-usi

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the html into a list of html nodes. The list of nodes will preserve the DOM order and give what you want.

Check the [parseFragment](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#parseFragment-java.lang.String-org.jsoup.nodes.Element-java.lang.String-) method :

This method will give you a list of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String html = ""
        + "<div class=\"text\">"
        + "    First Text"
        + "    <br>"
        + "    <br>"
        + "    <div style=\"margin:20px; margin-top:5px; \">"
        + "    <table cellpadding=\"5\">"
        + "        <tbody><tr>"
        + "            <td class=\"alt2\">"
        + "                <div>"
        + "                    Written by <b>excedent</b>"
        + "                </div>"
        + "                <div style=\"font-style:italic\">quote message</div>"
        + "            </td>"
        + "            </tr></tbody>"
        + "    </table>"
        + "    </div>Second Text<br>"
        + "        <br>"
        + "        <img class=\"img\" src=\"https://developer.android.com/_static/images/android/touchicon-180.png\"><br>"
        + "        <br>"
        + "        Third Text"
        + "    </div>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    List<String> rootTexts = doc.select("div.text").first().textNodes().stream()
        .map(node -> node.text().trim())
        .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(rootTexts);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[First Text, Second Text, Third Text]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late, but the correct way to do what you want to do is this. For your outermost `<div>`, instead of getting the child elements using `Element.children()`, you'll want to use `Element.childNodes()` instead.

`Element.children()` only returns child `Elements`, in which text is not included.

`Element.childNodes()` returns all child nodes, which includes `TextNodes` and `Elements`.

This solution works for me.